# Interpretation of HeavisideTheta Integration Output

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I need to integrate integrals of the type

```
Integrate[Boole[2 k*q >= Absolute[p^2 - k^2 - q^2]], q]
```

where $q$, $k$, and $p$ go from $0$ to $1$.

To learn to interpret the *Mathematica* output what I first evaluated (as a test) was

```
Integrate[Boole[2 k*q > (p^2 - k^2 - q^2)], {q, 0, 1},
          Assumptions -> 0 < k < 1 && 0 < p < 1]
```

Performing the integral by hand I find $1-{\rm max}(0,p-k)$ as a result. The *Mathematica* result yields the following piecewise function

\begin{cases}
1 & 0 < k < 1\mathtt{\;\&\&\;}p > 0\mathtt{\;\&\&\;}k-p \ge 0\\
1 + k - p & \mathtt{True}
\end{cases}

OK, the first line of the output I can interpret as a new Heaviside function which tells me that $k\geq p$ but what does the second line of the output try to tell me? Is there a convenient way to transform the piecewise output into $\min$, $\max$ functions or construct new Heaviside functions?

Comment: I wonder if you are reading the `Piecewise` expression backwards: this is telling you that, for $k \ge p$, the value of the integral is $1$; in all other cases, the integral has the value corresponding to the `True` condition, i.e. $1+k-p$ in this case. Notice also that you can have MMA `Simplify` your conditions: try `Assuming[{0 < k < 1, 0 < p < 1}, Simplify@Integrate[Boole[2 k q >= p^2 - k^2 - q^2], {q, 0, 1}]]`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the quick answer! Ok Simplify makes the result much easier to read and I also understood now that `True` means that the following expression is true for all cases not mentioned in the above conditions but still I wonder if one can transform such piecewise expressions into other expressions like max,min functions or new boole functions automatically? Or do I have to go through the mathematica expressions by hand to create those functions?

Comment: I don't know of an automated way to do what you ask. As a side note, frankly I find find the piece-wise output much more readable than the same thing expressed as a max function.

Comment: @MarcoB If i solve the original problem with the abosolute function in the Boole function my piecewise function cases get messy and lengthy while in the min max representation I still get some handy expressions which are not that long. That is why I want to to try avoid piecewise expressions.

Comment: ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep[%]``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @Michael E2, we could use:

```
pw = Integrate[Boole[2 k*q > (p^2-k^2-q^2)], {q,0,1}, Assumptions -> 0<k<1 && 0<p<1];

unit = Simplify`PWToUnitStep[pw]
```

> (1-UnitStep[-1+k]) (1-UnitStep[-k]) UnitStep[k-p] (1-UnitStep[-p])+(1+k-p) (1+UnitStep[-1+k]+UnitStep[-k]-UnitStep[k-p]+UnitStep[-p]-UnitStep[-k] UnitStep[-p]-(1-UnitStep[k-p]) (UnitStep[-k]+UnitStep[-p]-UnitStep[-k] UnitStep[-p])-UnitStep[-1+k] (1+UnitStep[-k]-UnitStep[k-p]+UnitStep[-p]-UnitStep[-k] UnitStep[-p]-(1-UnitStep[k-p]) (UnitStep[-k]+UnitStep[-p]-UnitStep[-k] UnitStep[-p])))

This is a bit messy, so it would be nice to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) this and reduce the number of [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) objects:

```
Simplify[unit] //InputForm
```

> Piecewise[{{1, Inequality[0, Less, k, Less, 1] && k >= p && 
>       p > 0}}, 1 + k - p]

Naturally, this returned the original [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) object. However, it is possible to convert pw to a simpler [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) version as follows:

```
Simplify[
    pw,
    ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 1000 Boole[!FreeQ[#, Piecewise]]&),
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Simplify`PWToUnitStep}
]
```

> 1+k-p+(k-p) (-1+UnitStep[-1+k]) (-1+UnitStep[-k]) UnitStep[k-p] (-1+UnitStep[-p])

The [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) penalizes the presence of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) objects, and the [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option includes the [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) transformation.

Comment: ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep`` looks like something one might include in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions.  Would you consider posting it there?

Comment: The title to this question is about HeavisideTheta interpretation yet nowhere in the comments or answers does HeavisideTheta occur.